# microphone noise cancelation using two mics using AND function

Tags: noise, microphone

First things first, I will clear up that this question is not about external noise cancellation.
Cheap microphone generates unwanted static noise, so i decided to array two microphones and use "AND" function to filter out signal that is coming out only from both microphones, because each microphone will have different noise from another, noise will be left out, leaving only recorded signal

1. will this work ?
2. how to make this ?
3. will phase be an issue ? even if they will be placed really close

Comment: How exactly do you define an "AND" function on two analog signals?

Comment: @DaveTweed for example signal A is 400hz sine wave and 800hz sine, signal B is 400hz sine wave and 1000hz sine, output will be 400hz sine only

Comment: I suspected as much. You're defining a kind of frequency-sensitive "noise gate", the implementation of which would require a large amount of DSP horsepower, and would be difficult to implement in real time (i.e., with low latency). You'd be better off spending the money on a better microphone to begin with.

Answer (score 4):

AND is a logical function that doesn't apply to analog signals.  It makes no sense in this context.

What you want to do is average (or add, just differs in gain) the two signals.  If the noise from each mic is uncorrelated to the other, then this noise will be reduced by 3 dB.

Yes, this is a valid approach.

Comment: The microphones have some physical separation, and their output signals will be out of phase. Wouldn't adding those signals together sound 'wrong'?

Comment: @vof: For frequencies where the physical separation is significant, you end up with a directional "array", although in this case with only two array elements.  Exploiting the phased array effect to get  a directionality can be useful, but if you just want to reduce noise put the mics close together.